# Syntax errors passing array to functions

Tags: c, arrays, function, syntax

new here to the site, though I have searched through here for answers to questions before. I was wondering if someone could give me a little guidance & help with a program I'm writing.

It is supposed to have a user enter values into an array and perform actions on the array. For some reason though, when using a function to enter/print/manipulate the array, I'm getting syntax errors when i compile the program ( using the command line):

(9): error C2061: identifier 'enterNum'

(9): error C2059: ';'

(9): error C2059: 'type'

(85): error C2061: identifier 'enterNum'

(85): error C2059: ';'

(85): error C2059: 'type'

(85): error C2059: ','

(95): error C2143: missing ')' before 'constant'

(95): error C2143: missing '{' before 'constant'

(95): error C2059: ''

(95): error C2059: ')'

They all seem like simple errors but I don't know what I'm doing wrong. any help would be appreciated. Here is the code from my program that the errors are coming from

```
#define MAX 100
int ar[MAX];
```

starting at line 9

```
array enterNum (int ar[], MAX)
array printArray (int ar[], MAX)
void mean( const int ar[],int n)
void reverseArray( const int ar[], int n)
```

line 85

```
array enterNum(int ar[], MAX) // Function for entering all elements of array
{
size_t i;
for( i = 0; i < n; i++) // loop to enter values
{
    printf("ar[%d] = ", i);
    scanf("%d\n", &ar[i]);
}
 }
```

line 95

```
void printArray(int ar[], MAX)
{
puts("The entered array is:");

for( i = 0; i < n; i++) //prints all elements of the array
    printf("ar[%d] = %d",i, ar[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need semicolons starting at line 9 (and possibly other places)

```
array enterNum (int ar[], MAX);
array printArray (int ar[], MAX);
void mean( const int ar[],int n);
void reverseArray( const int ar[], int n);
```

Also your use of `MAX` is wrong in certain places. The pre-compiler effectively substitues the macro by its value whenever it encounters the macro. Using `MAX` in the function prototypes is wrong.

Comment: thats what i figured, i had them but Im not sure why i deleted them. Im using visual studio and its been throwing me some weird errors and suggestions lately

Comment: Just deal with the first error/suggestion it throws at you. Very often solving that first error automatically solves a lot of subsequent errors.

Comment: So instead of using MAX in the prototype what should i use? just 100?

Comment: No, no, no. You need a type (and optionally a name) in the prototypes (both the type and name are mandatory in the function definition). Use `size_t` or `int`; as in `array enterNum(int ar[], size_t len);`

Comment: i also have an error that doesnt make sense... its saying that its missing a ')' before '(' in line 11.... which i dont get

Comment: an error in line 11 is sometimes caused by something wrong in line 10 (or even 9). Pay attention to semicolons and mismatched parenthesis.